# What is the meaning of "Rb is in the active state"?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, cancer, cell-cycle

I am reading about cyclins, cdks and Rb ([Retinoblastoma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retinoblastoma_protein)) and some of the terminology is not clear to me.

I understand that when CDK phosphorylates Rb, it disconnects from E2F, and E2F can act as a transcription factor. My question is about the terminology.

My questions are:

> 1. When people say "Rb is active", do they mean "active = phosphorylated state" (where E2F is free from Rb) or do they mean "active = not phosphorylated state"?
> 2. Does "active cyclin" means cyclin is going to join CDK and cell cycle proceeds? or is "active cyclin = cyclin is not activating CDK and cell cycle paused"?
> 3. Active CDK means CDK is activated by cyclin and cell cycle can proceed?
>
> In general, Maybe one can say that binding (Rb with E2F or Cyclin with CKD) means activation and disconnecting means inactivation?

Thanks!

[image]

(Image source: Kolch, Walter, et al. "[The role of Raf kinases in malignant transformation.](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-role-of-Raf-kinases-in-malignant-Kolch-Kotwaliwale/e778edccb0b3a9b9683f5d4c4b805aafc9707b67)" Expert reviews in molecular medicine 4.8 (2002): 1-18.)

Answer (score 3):

1. The terminology of "Rb is active/inactive" refers to the activity of inhibiting E2F.
   So active Rb inhibits E2F, while inactive Rb doesn't inhibit E2F. 
   With regard to Rb and phosphorylation - the story seems to be more complex ([[1]](http://genesdev.cshlp.org/content/30/13/1492.full) describes Rb as an enigma).
   According to [[2]](https://cdn.elifesciences.org/articles/02872/elife-02872-v2.pdf) (this quote is from the summary of the paper by eLife):

   > Narasimha, Kaulich, Shapiro et al. now present biochemical analyses of
   >   Rb proteins that show— completely unexpectedly—that the cyclin D
   >   complex adds just one phosphate group to Rb during the G1 phase,
   >   although this group can be added to one of fourteen different sites.
   >   The resulting 'mono-phosphorylated' Rb varieties can each sequester
   >   different transcription factors and stop them working.
   > At the
   >   restriction point, many more phosphate groups are then rapidly added,
   >   and the Rb protein is inactivated by a different cyclin. This
   >   cyclin—called Cyclin E—then drives cells into the next phase of the
   >   cell cycle. Establishing how cyclin E is activated is a priority for
   >   future research.
2. + 3. [Wikipedia's Cyclin-dependent kinase (CDK) page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclin-dependent_kinase) says:

   > By definition, a CDK binds a regulatory protein called a cyclin. Without cyclin, CDK has little kinase activity; only the cyclin-CDK complex is an active kinase.

   [Wikipedia's Protein kinase page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_kinase) says:

   > A protein kinase is a kinase enzyme that modifies other molecules, mostly proteins, by chemically adding phosphate groups to them (phosphorylation).

   And here is a nice visual explanation from [Life: The Science of Biology (10th edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1464141266):

   [image: CDK]

   So both "active CDK" and "active cyclin-CDK complex" (and according to [the other answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/74335/50613), also "active cyclin") refer to the case in which a cyclin is bound to a CDK to form a cyclin-CDK complex, such that the CDK might phosphorylate some substrate.
   (I didn't mention the cell cycle here on purpose, as I am not an expert, and so I am wary of claiming that an active CDK always pushes the cell cycle forward. If I understand correctly, we still don't know exactly how each cyclin-CDK complex affects the cell cycle.)

As for your last question:

> In general, Maybe one can say that binding (Rb with E2F or Cyclin with
>   CKD) means activation and disconnecting means inactivation?

As mentioned above, you could say that about a cyclin and its CDK.
Unfortunately, you can't say that in general. E2F here is a counter example (it is inhibited when Rb binds to it and activated when Rb disconnects from it).
However, you could say that in general, when something binds to a protein, the protein might change its shape, which might lead to activating or inhibiting some function.

---

[[1]](http://genesdev.cshlp.org/content/30/13/1492.full) Dyson, Nicholas J. "RB1: a prototype tumor suppressor and an enigma." Genes & development 30.13 (2016): 1492-1502.

[[2]](https://cdn.elifesciences.org/articles/02872/elife-02872-v2.pdf) Narasimha, Anil M., et al. "Cyclin D activates the Rb tumor suppressor by mono-phosphorylation." Elife 3 (2014): e02872.

Answer (score 2):

> Rb: The *underphosphorylated*, active form of RB1 interacts with E2F1
>   and represses its transcription activity, leading to cell cycle
>   arrest. (UniProt: [P06400](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P06400))
>
> Cyclin-D: Regulatory component of the cyclin D1-CDK4 (DC) complex that
>   *phosphorylates* and *inhibits* members of the retinoblastoma (RB) protein family including RB1 and regulates the cell-cycle during G1/S
>   transition. (UniProt: [P24385](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P24385))

Active cyclin-D (i.e., cyclin-D in complex with CDK4) phosporylates (i.e., inactivates) Rb.

Comment: This answer makes complete sense to me and probably most folks who answer questions here, but given OP's confusion it might be helpful to explain a bit further and state very explicitly what's going on.